# User interface (how to change background)

Tags: objective-c, user-interface, xcode4

How i may change background for window?
I have a Button, set *Style* "**Round rect**", set *Type* "**On Off**", set *State* "**On**"-how i may change background color from gray to blue?
And how i may change background for all app?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

In iOS window based application , you have to create the link between UserInterface to the Code.

1. Add IBAction in your app delegate file. Let say "changeBG"

-(void) IBAction changeBG
{
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}

1. Connect the Interface with code by Open XIB and control-click to AppDelegate, when popup appear select changeBG

For UIControlEvent , I recommend UIControlEventTouchUpInside for beginner.
That's it. Hope you can do it.

control-click from your button to

Comment: OSX app should be very similar to iOS.